# Recoil - single atom vs multiple atoms

Tags: reactjs

I have an index file that contains a lot of atoms for a wizard I've created.

I thought about moving all the creations -

```
export const foo1State = atom<string>({
    key: "foo1State",
    default: "",
});
export const foo2State = atom<boolean>({
    key: "foo2State",
    default: false,
});
```

into one using JSON -

```
    export const fooStates = atom<fooState>({
        key: "fooStates",
        default: {
                     foo1State: string = "",
                     foo2State: boolean = false,
                  }
     });
```

Is that a better approach?
I'll mention that all that inputs are changing frequently so need to consider the renders.

What do you think?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have separate atoms for each state, then you can independently subscribe to each one. If you combine them all into one, a component that renders `foo1State` will re-render every time you update `foo2State` and vice versa. This can be problematic if the atom gets really big.

If you don't have any particular reason why you would need to hold `foo1State` and `foo2State` in single atom, go with your first approach, and keep them in separate atoms.